# Excel function to repeat values based on id's and subid's

Tags: excel

I have the below table:

```
ID  SubID   Data    Covered Under
1   A   Item1   
1   B   Item1   Scenario 1
2       Item2   Scenario 3
3       Item3   
4   A   Item4   
4   B   Item4   Scenario 2
5   A   Item5   Scenario 4
5   B   Item5   Scenario 5
```

If any of the Items have been covered under any Scenario, I want to add a column that shows that its Partially covered which should look like this:

```
ID  SubID   Data    Coverage           Covered Under
1   A   Item1   Partial Coverage    
1   B   Item1   Partial Coverage    Scenario 1
2       Item2   Full Coverage           Scenario 3
3       Item3   No Coverage 
4   A   Item4   Partial Coverage    
4   B   Item4   Partial Coverage    Scenario 2
4   A   Item5   Partial Coverage    Scenario 4
4   B   Item5   Partial Coverage    Scenario 5
```

Any idea's on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested if and COUNTIFS:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,"<>")=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2),"Full Coverage",IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,"<>"),"Partial Coverage","No Coverage"))
```

[image]